My visit is for two weeks but my host bought insurance for two months is it okay
My trip is for two weeks but my host bought insurance for 2 months is it okay?

Why do you think this would not be OK?

Insurance for what?

@nvoigt Presumably the mandatory insurance for a Schengen application.

What did your host say when you asked them? Often insurance for Schengen visa applications can be cancelled, if you’re worried about it and haven’t submitted your application yet, you can ask your host to cancel the policy and get a new one for two weeks.

Is there a significant price difference? Will you have to reimburse the host?

If anything, it might benefit your application as it might be considered a factor in granting you a visa with a longer duration.

I'd think you'd want insurance covering longer than your planned trip.  Assume you're injured on day 13 of a planned 14 day trip and need to spend 10 days in a hospital before you're recovered enough to go home.  You'd be in a very bad financial situation if your policy only covered the first 20% of your care.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Insurance typically covers all expenses as long as the accident happened (or illness started) on a day that was covered

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: A big consideration for Schengen visas (and many others) is convincing the authorities that you aren’t intending to overstay your claimed itinerary.  One might reasonably worry that longer insurance could be viewed as a red flag of actually planning to stay the longer period.  The explanations given in Petr’s answer should set this worry to rest, but it’s not crazy to wonder about it.

In addition to the answer of @Anish Sheela (+1), there are many many reasons why someone may have insurance for a longer period than a trip. Some people get travel insurance as a part of a larger package (e.g. with a regular domestic medical insurance, or with a credit card, etc.), in which case it will often cover a whole year; some may have another unrelated trip lined up and get insurance to cover both periods; some insurance companies might not sell you insurance for a period less than X months, etc. So there is indeed nothing strange in this situation.

‘Permanent’ travel insurances (like those that come with home insurances or credit cards) are fundamentally different, though. They’re generally in effect all year round, but they nearly always have limits on what they actually cover; apart from some high-end corporate insurances, it would be very rare to find one that actually covers a whole year. For example, mine covers travel up to 60 days; if I stay out of the country for longer than 60 days, I still have an active travel insurance, but I’m no longer covered by it; I’d need an extension or a separate insurance to stay covered.

The insurance for the purpose of Schengen visa has to cover the duration of stay. If it's longer than the duration, there are no issues. Just make sure the rest of the documents clearly prove your intended entry and exit dates.
